# Can you see IP addresses of visitors to your sites.google.com page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sites

I read the question [How can I find the IP address for my visitors in Google Analytics Universal reports?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77297/how-can-i-find-the-ip-address-for-my-visitors-in-google-analytics-universal-repo), but wasn't sure if it applies to sites.google.com

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can see IP addresses of your visitors. You also cannot collect this information, as it goes against Google's policy of collecting personally identifiable information (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en).

Edit: I should clarify that although I haven't found anywhere where it says explicitly that sites.google.com doesn't allow for the collection of IP address, I am merely extending Google's policy to those sites as well, afterall, why whould Google not allow PII collection through their Analytics on all non-Google sites, but yet allow it for theirs (sites.google.com)?