# Is there a way for GA to track internal network traffic for a private network?

Tags: google-analytics

I've been doing a lot of research on whether or not GA would be usable inside of a private network such as a `192.X.X.X` or `10.X.X.X` instead of reporting the publicly held IP for each node. On the surface, it looks like this a no-go.  However, I did find [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/283345/how-can-we-open-our-firewall-to-allow-google-analytics) on SF that seems to imply that this could be possible.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Is internet access blocked like in the question you linked?

Comment: Not blocked entirely, but it is monitored with certain classes of websites blocked like adult content, social media. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official documentation on Intranet Usage from Google: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009688?hl=en As it states even if it is just internal, the intranet still needs to have a FQDN to track data. But it will only track users as unique if the external ip addresses are different.  Internal networks will look like returning visitors.

As for Just internal users with local ip's this is not possible.  You would need to install a self hosted solution like piwik which will allow you to do just what you are looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics will usually be able to track an intranet website.

GA requires that client browsers run JavaScript.  Client browsers must be able to send data to `www.google-analytics.com`.

GA does not require that a site be public.  It does not require that Google crawlers be able to reach the site.   It does not require Google to access server logs.

To test it out:

1. Sign up for Google Analytics
2. Put the tracking snippet onto the intranet site
3. Open Google Analytics real time reporting
4. Visit the intranet site in your web browser
5. Verify that your visit appears in the real time reporting

Comment: The website is publicly accessible, it's the client machines on the Intranet that we are trying to tracking using their private IP addresses.  I would like to be able to track the private IP addresses (192.x.x.x) as opposed to the public IP address held by the router that workstation sits behind.

Comment: Google Analytics does not track IP addresses of clients at all: [How can I find the IP address for my visitors in Google Analytics Universal reports?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77297/how-can-i-find-the-ip-address-for-my-visitors-in-google-analytics-universal-repo)