# Google Analytics Report by IP Address

Tags: google-analytics, ip-address

How can I create a GA report to show me visitors from a specific IP address, I know I can go to Admin>view and filter by IP that way however, I would prefer a report in the current profile.

Comment: GA doesn't record IP addresses of users.  See [How can I find the IP address for my visitors in Google Analytics Universal reports?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77297/how-can-i-find-the-ip-address-for-my-visitors-in-google-analytics-universal-repo)

Comment: I know the IP address I wanted to create a report for visitors from that IP address. I did this by creating a new view and then filtering to include the IP address.

Comment: Yes, you can create filters by IP address as GA collects the data, but GA doesn't store IP address for later use in reports or advanced segments.