# How can we pass custom variables in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, custom-dimensions, custom-variables

I have a task of getting username, company and other desired data in a Google Analytics report.

I want to know how I can get them in report. I tried this:
[How can I find the IP address for my visitors in Google Analytics Universal reports?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77297/how-can-i-find-the-ip-address-for-my-visitors-in-google-analytics-universal-repo)

but I can't get that data.

Answer (score 1):

An easier approach would be to use [User ID tracking in Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en). That way you dont have to use too many custom variables. Whenever you need user-wise data, pull in that as a secondary dimension and do a vlookup with your application data.